# How to suspend current thread for 20 seconds in java?

Tags: java

How to suspend current thread for 20 seconds in java?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Thread.sleep](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)(20*1000);

Answer (score 7):

[Thread.sleep(20000)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

Answer (score 3):

you may also want to include the try catch:

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(20*1000);
} catch(InterruptedException e) { }
```

Comment: should be InterruptedException, not all exceptions in general